# Graphics Program Works on Windows but not on Mac

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I wrote this program in java using swing. When I run this on my Mac each time `repaint()` is called fifty new blue points are made and the old blue points are erased. I have been doing a lot of research to try and fix this issue and I have had not luck. Then today in my computer science class I find out that the program works on the windows computers that are in the classroom. My question is why is this the case and how can I fix this so that the program works on my Mac? Also on a side note I am relatively new to using swing in java so I was wondering if I am organizing everything correctly and if I can do anything different?

This is the class where I draw everything within the JPanel.

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class BarnsleyFern extends JPanel 
{
   private double newX,x=0;
   private double newY,y=0;
   public BarnsleyFern()
   {  
      ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
         {
            repaint();
         }
      };
      Timer timer = new Timer(100,action);
      //timer.start();
      MouseListener mouse = new MouseListener()
      {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
         {
            //repaint();
         }
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
         {
         }
         public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
         {
         }
         public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event)
         {
         }
         public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event)
         {
         } 
      };
      MouseMotionListener mouseMotion = new MouseMotionListener()
      {
         public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)   
         {
            repaint();
         }
         public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)
         {
            repaint();
         }
      };   
      addMouseListener(mouse);
      addMouseMotionListener(mouseMotion);
   }
   public void paintComponent(Graphics window)
   {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)window;
      g2d.translate(360,800);
      fern(window);
   }
   public void fern(Graphics window)
   {
      Color newColor = new Color((int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256));
      for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
      {
         window.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         int rand = (int)(Math.random()*100);
         if(rand<1)
         {
            newX=0;
            newY=0.16*y;
         }
         else if(rand<86)
         {
            newX=0.85*x + 0.04*y;
            newY=0.85*y - 0.04*x + 1.6;
         }  
         else if(rand<93)
         {
            newX=0.20*x - 0.26*y;
            newY=0.23*x + 0.22*y + 1.6;
         }
         else
         {
            newX=0.28*y - 0.15*x;
            newY=0.26*x + 0.24*y + 0.44;
         }
         window.fillOval((int)(newX*165.364),-(int)(newY*80.014),2,2);   
         x=newX;
         y=newY;
      }
   }
}
```

This is the class that sets up the JFrame and adds the JPanel.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 

public class BarnsleyFernRunner 
{
   public BarnsleyFernRunner()
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setTitle("Barnsley Fern");
      frame.setSize(800,800);
      frame.setLocation(300,0);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLayout(null);
      BarnsleyFern panel= new BarnsleyFern();
      panel.setSize(800,800);
      panel.setOpaque(true);
      panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      frame.add(panel);

      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
      BarnsleyFernRunner runner = new BarnsleyFernRunner();
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, the first thing I notice is the fact that you seem to have broken the paint chain

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);`  - I think I might stop responding to questions with this in it

Comment: *you seem to have broken the paint chain* - in English that means you haven't invoked `super.paintComponent(...)` as the first statement in your painting method. It is the job of a Swing component to clear the background before doing custom painting. So in reality the Mac version is working correctly and the Windows version does what you want by chance. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: If you want to do incremental painting then you should either 1) paint to a BufferedImage or 2) keep an ArrayList of Objects you want to paint. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for more information and working examples of both approaches. Also, you should NOT be generating random colors in a painting method. You can't control when the component will be repainted and you don't want to keep changing the colors each time.

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer for the help.

Comment: Thank you @camickr for the help too.

Answer (score 0):

The "major" issue is, you're breaking the paint chain requirements...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics window)
{
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)window;
   g2d.translate(360,800);
   fern(window);
}
```

The `super` implementation of `paintComponent` does something, something important, unless you're prepared to take over that responsibility, you should make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` first

You issue isn't helped by...

```
  frame.setSize(800,800);
  frame.setLocation(300,0);
  frame.setResizable(false);
  frame.setLayout(null);
  panel.setSize(800,800);
  panel.setOpaque(true);
```

You should keep the default `BorderLayout`, it will make your life a lot simpler.

Simply by updating the `BarnsleyFern` to override the `getPreferredSize` you gain a much more flexible solution.  This means you `pack` the window and the available content size will be the preferred size of the contents, as apposed to the size of the window MINUS the frame decorations.

```
public class BarnsleyFern extends JPanel {
    //...
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 800);
    }
```

Based upon...

```
ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        repaint();
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(100, action);
//timer.start();
```

I suspect you're hoping to get a compounding paint, where the `x`/`y` properties are updated on each paint cycle.

Well, that's not going to work, for a number of reasons.  You've found one.  `Graphics` is a shared resource, every component painted in a given paint cycle will use the same `Graphics` instance, this means you could end up with dirty paints (and as a side effect, the result you seem to be looking for), but as you've discovered, it doesn't always work.

Painting can also occur for any number of reasons, many without you control or knowledge.

Painting should paint the current state, it shouldn't modify it.  This is what your `Timer` should be doing.

You need to devise a model which will allow a incremental change each time the `Timer` ticks, the component will then use the model to simply paint the current state

I would recommend reading:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

for more details